# Error installing Xamarin.Auth from NuGet

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

When installing `Xamarin.Auth` to my project with NuGet, I get this error:

> Could not install package 'Validation 2.0.4.14103'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Are you trying to install an iOS package into a PCL library?

Comment: Hi, i dont really know what im doing scince this is my first time using xamarin.forms, Im trying to install the Xamarin.auth Nuget package to my Project from visual studios nuget installler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the NuGet dependency behaviour is set to 'lowest' and `Validation 2.0.4.14103` is not compatible with `Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0`

Here is a workaround:

1. Install the `Validation` NuGet package first, using the latest version `2.3.7`.
2. Then install `Xamarin.Auth`, and it should work as expected without the error.

Comment: What is this "Validation" NuGet package? Is this the Microsoft jQuery one? Can someone please post the project page for it?

Comment: @ShayOhayon ['Method input validation and runtime checks that report errors or throw exceptions when failures are detected'](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Validation/). It's a dependency of `PCLCrypto` which is a dependency of `Xamarin.Auth`.